# Coffee Urns left out throughout the week?

Tags: halacha, minhag, food

Many people still keep to the [halacha](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25077&st=&pgnum=152) that one isn't allowed to drink from water kept in metal overnight.

- How would one be allowed to drink from a Coffee Urn on Shabbos?
- How could one drink from a can of soda?

Comment: Its only if it is opened not just in metal

Comment: This sounds like a question for a Chabad rabbi specifically. It's not a halacha I have ever heard of.  I'd love to know the source of it.  On the other hand, I know people who will not drink out of Aluminum cans because of a fear of alzheimers being caused by aluminum.

Comment: @avi, it actually comes from the Gemara (Niddah 17a) in a list of things that are dangerous to health.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The footnotes there in Shulchan Aruch Harav refer, among others, to a letter by the Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l ([Igros Kodesh, vol. 2, pp. 143-145](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15907&pgnum=170)), in which he discusses this issue. He concludes that this is one of those examples of things that "since many people are accustomed to doing it, then *shomer pesayim Hashem*, 'Hashem guards the simple.'"

[He notes that this particular rule seems to be a non-scientific type of danger (ענין סגוליי), and therefore this rationale can be used to ignore it entirely - unlike things that are indeed recognized as potential medical dangers to health, where even *shomer pesayim* only mitigates the danger but still requires one to take appropriate precautions.]

With soda cans, anyway, we might not even need that consideration. In the paragraph before that the Rebbe suggests that the word *keli* should be understood as narrowly as possible. So we can suggest that sealed soda can is not a *keli*, because it has no opening (as indeed is the case as far as hilchos Shabbos).

Comment: "as indeed is the case as far as hilchos Shabbos" - according to some, including Chabad.